# How to convert an array of dictionaries to an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript

How can I easily convert this (array of dictionaries):

```
[ { a: 1,
    b: 1,
    c: 'something',
    d: 1 },
  { a: 23443,
    b: 2111,
    c: 'something 2',
    d: 1456 }
]
```

to this (array of arrays):

```
[ [ 1,
    1,
    'something',
    1 ],
  [ 23443,
    2111,
    'something2',
    1456 ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

*The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array*

*The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object*

Try this:

```js
var input = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 'something',
  d: 1
}, {
  a: 23443,
  b: 2111,
  c: 'something2',
  d: 1456
}];
var op = input.map(function(inp) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i in inp) {
    arr.push(inp[i]);
  }
  return arr;
});
console.log(op);
```

**OR use `Object.keys(YOUR_OBJECT)`:**

```js
var input = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 'something',
  d: 1
}, {
  a: 23443,
  b: 2111,
  c: 'something2',
  d: 1456
}];
var op = input.map(function(inp) {
  return Object.keys(inp).map(function(key) {
    return inp[key];
  })
});
console.log(op);
```